# Google App Script/Javascript - Not able to loop through up to the end of Column in Google Spreadsheet using Google App Script

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to scrape through 3000+ data using Google Spreadsheet. I used Google App Script to loop  on every cell in Column A and arrange it on a different column. I am able to create a simple script that will loop through a cell, scrape the data, and insert it to the designated column. The problem is, the script that I made won't scrape or loop up until the end of the column. It can only scrape up to 1654 of the column even though I have 3000+ data on that column. The data is consist of multiple information of an individual The information is consist of Name, Day, Date, Time and description of the customer. **Take note that 1 data is inserted into 1 cell in the column. Meaning I have 3000+ cell with data in Column A.**

Sample Data:

John Doe Tuesday, 06/21/2021, Bought 1 pack of Bubblegum

Trish Smith Monday, 06/21/2021, Bought 1 pack of Bubblegum

Karen Peralta Thursday, 06/21/2021, Bought 1 pack of Bubblegum

**Additional Question. Is there limitation in looping through every cell using google app script?**

```
function rawDataAlteration() {
  var days = new Array('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday');
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Raw Data');
  var data = spreadsheet.getRange('A1:A').getValues();
  var filteredData = new Array();
  for (q in data) {
    if(data[q] != "") {
      filteredData.push(data[q]);
    }
  }
  for (x in filteredData) {
    if (filteredData[x] != "") {
      var convertedToArray = filteredData[x][0].split(',');
      var nametoArray = convertedToArray[0].split(' ');
      var name = new Array();
      var day = "";
      var columnNum = Math.floor(x)+1;
      var nameColumn = 'A'+ columnNum;
      var dayColumn = 'B' + columnNum;
      var dateColumn = 'C' + columnNum;
      var shiftColumn = 'D' + columnNum;
      for(let i in nametoArray){
          let found = false;
          for(let j in days){
              if(nametoArray[i] == days[j]){
                  day = days[j];
                  found = true;
              }
          }
          if(!found){
              name.push(nametoArray[i]);
          }
      }
      var columnB = spreadsheet.getRange(nameColumn).setValue(name.toString().replace(',', ' '));
      var columnD = spreadsheet.getRange(dayColumn).setValue(day);
      var columnD = spreadsheet.getRange(dateColumn).setValue(convertedToArray[1]);
      // Logger.log(filteredData);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, each script execution can only last [six minutes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations). If your script takes longer than that, it'll be interrupted.

Your snippet shows that you're using quite a few `getRange()` and `setValue()` inside a loop, which makes the processing slower and it's not recommended.

According to the [best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations), a better way would be to batch the calls. In your case, that means to work with all the data using arrays in the loop and then do `setValues()` outside the loop.